# Get 90th percentile in jmeter in unix command line

Tags: unix, jmeter

I would like to display the 90th percentile for a request in jmeter using unix command line.iam not able to do so.

i have enabled the flags in jmeter.properties are aggregate_rpt_pct1 =90 , aggregate_rpt_pct2=95 & aggregate_rpt_pct3=99.

But still iam not able to display.Iam using the commands

**./jmeter.sh -n -t examples/LTTest_unix.jmx -l /testing12.csv -e -o /bin/outputreports**

Iam not able to get the 90th percentile.

please find the screenshot for the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6siq.png)

please help on this.What should i do to get the 90th,99th percentile in non-gui mode in linux

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see 90% percentile for the same in the unix command line you need to install [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd) and run an extra command to generate the same from the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles).

1. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/), you will need to execute the following command from "bin" folder of your JMeter installation for the same

   ```
   wget https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/ -O ../lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar
   ```
2. Install [cmdrunner](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:kg.apc%20AND%20a:cmdrunner). You will need to run the following commands for the same:

   ```
   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.3/cmdrunner-2.3.jar -P ../lib/
   ```

   and

   ```
   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.3/cmdrunner-2.3.jar -P ../lib/
   ```
3. Install necessary plugins: [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD) and [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/). You will need to run the following commands for the same:

   ```
   java -cp ../lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
   ```

   and

   ```
   ./PluginsManagerCMD.sh install jpgc-cmd,jpgc-synthesis
   ```
4. Run your test using the same command you're using for the same
5. Generate CSV version of the Aggregate Report, you can run below command for the same:

   ```
   ./JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv /desired/path/to/CSV/version/of/aggregate/report.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/test/result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```

---

In addition

1. You don't need to amend any JMeter properties to get 90 percentile, all your overrides match [default values](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#aggregate_report_graph) they are the same
2. Any configuration overrides should go to [**user.properties** file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter), this way they can survive upgrades